# Why would React.render not render correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a bit new to React so I may be missing something obvious, but I've used similar ways of rendering HTML from a CMS into a partially React DOM (just the component, everything else is provided via jsp.) I can see the data passing in correctly, but it seems like the ReactDOM.render isn't doing anything. Any idea what I'm missing/doing wrong?

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

/**** Component ****/
import FulfillmentInfoDrawer from "REACT_COMPONENTS/dialogs/fulfillmentInfoDrawer/FulfillmentInfoDrawer";

/**** Utilities ****/
import {Helper} from 'REACT_UTILITIES/Helper';


function fulfillmentFlyout () {

    Helper.waitForElm('#react-fulfillmentFlyout').then(() =>{

        let insertFlyoutDiv = document.getElementById('react-fulfillmentFlyout'),
            fulfillmentType = insertFlyoutDiv.dataset.fulfillmenttype,
            flyoutOne = Helper.decodeHTMLEntities(insertFlyoutDiv.getElementsByClassName('flyoutOne')[0].outerHTML),
            flyoutTwo = Helper.decodeHTMLEntities(insertFlyoutDiv.getElementsByClassName('flyoutTwo')[0].outerHTML),
            flyoutTrigger = Helper.decodeHTMLEntities(insertFlyoutDiv.getElementsByClassName('flyoutTwoTrigger')[0].outerHTML);

        // console.log('Params',insertFlyoutDiv, fulfillmentType, flyoutOne, flyoutTwo, flyoutTrigger);

        if(insertFlyoutDiv && fulfillmentType) {
            const getFulfillmentInfoDrawer = () => {
                return <FulfillmentInfoDrawer drawerType={fulfillmentType} drawer1Content={flyoutOne}
                                              drawer2Content={flyoutTwo} drawer2Trigger={flyoutTrigger}
                                              oldStyleFlyout={true}/>;
            }
            console.log('render', getFulfillmentInfoDrawer());

            ReactDOM.render(<FulfillmentInfoDrawer drawerType={fulfillmentType} drawer1Content={flyoutOne}
                                                   drawer2Content={flyoutTwo} drawer2Trigger={flyoutTrigger}
                                                   oldStyleFlyout={true}/>, document.getElementById('react-fulfillmentFlyout'));
        }
    });
}


window.addEventListener('fulfillmentFlyout:BCC', fulfillmentFlyout);
```

Comment: What exactly does `Helper.decodeHTMLEntities`? And what does `<FulfillmentInfoDrawer />` expect to get in its properties. I have a feeling that you mix up JSX and HTML because they *look* somewhat similar. They are *very* different things.

Comment: decodeHTMLEntities converts html entities to what they should be visually, so things like @amp; turning into &.  Each variable in <FulfillmentInfoDrawer /> is taken from JSP DOM so you're correct it's HTML, but put into a string so I can put it into the JSX there.  Is that not possible?

Comment: this piece of JSX `return <FulfillmentInfoDrawer drawerType={fulfillmentType} drawer1Content={flyoutOne} drawer2Content={flyoutTwo} drawer2Trigger={flyoutTrigger} oldStyleFlyout={true} />` is compiled into this piece of JS `return React.createElement(FulfillmentInfoDrawer, {drawerType: fulfillmentType, drawer1Content: flyoutOne, drawer2Content: flyoutTwo, drawer2Trigger: flyoutTrigger, oldStyleFlyout: true });`. So no, you can't use HTML markup in React like that.